# contact management - using SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm looking to use sharepoint to build a contact management system.
Has anyone done something similar or is there a third party i can just use.
Any tips/resources would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: check this http://blogs.technet.com/b/lystavlen/archive/2012/09/11/mini-crm-in-sharepoint-online.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I've seen lead management systems built into SharePoint, which is the somewhat more complicated cousin to contact management and it works well, though it takes a bit of work if you want it to not look 'SharePoint-y' (InfoPath, SharePoint Designer or CSS and service calls).

SharePoint 2013 comes with an app for Contacts out of the box, but if you're doing a lot of contacts, you may end up being better off creating your own custom content types (easily done through the front-end or Designer). Content types such as 'Employee', 'Customer', 'Business Contact', etc. each inheriting from a basic 'Contact' type.

It's easy enough to tie into Outlook or to hook up to existing SharePoint phone apps.

Beyond just using it for maintaining a list of contacts, you can use it for doing things like telling you which people haven't been contacted in 30 days or creating tasks that point back to the contact (using a custom display form with a lookup for tasks associated with that contact).

Comment: Thanks guys. So really it seems there is no out of the box solution.With the business contact manager in the SharePoint store is that only for online or can we also use it on premise
But thanks the tips

Comment: There is absolutely an out of the box method, which is the Contacts App that I mentioned above. It's just a built in list type. I'm just adding on to that that you may want to invest some time in learning how to create custom content types to better suit your particular purpose. It's front-end stuff and easily googleable.